# How can I run a scheduled task on a Windows 2008 R2 Domain Controller as a non-admin user?

Tags: security, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, scheduled-task

I'm trying to run an exe as a scheduled task on a Windows 2008 R2 Domain Controller.

The exe runs fine when I try and run it manually using an account which is a Domain Administrator, but I don't want to run scheduled tasks as a Domain Admin, for obvious reasons.

Since I can't set Local Admins on a Domain Controller, that isn't an option here.  I have added the user that the task should run as to "Log on as a batch job" in the group policy which is applied to domain controllers, but I'm still getting errors.

I'm just trying to use the regular Task Scheduler, not `AT`.

This works fine on the couple of Windows Server 2003 Domain Controllers we still have, but they are on their way out.  So I'm assuming this isn't an issue with the script itself.  At minimum I'd like to know for sure if I have the correct settings in place to allow a specific non-Domain admin user to run a script on a domain controller.

Update: User is included as Server Operator group in AD.  Batch file still doesn't run correctly.

Comment: I don't have time to test real quick, but if you add the user to "Server Operators" on the domain does that fix the issue?  That group will have "elevated" rights on a DC.  Not quite the extent of a domain admin, but just a cautionary warning.

Comment: I checked and the user was already a member of this group - that hasn't enabled them to run this script.

Comment: What errors are you getting, exactly? And what does your script do? I'm suspecting your script accesses some objects (files, registry, or the system logger) on which the assigned user has no permission. Please bear in mind that Windows 2008 R2 is much much much more secured than Windows 2003; objects that are readable by Everyone in Windows 2003 might be locked up in Windows 2008 R2.